# 'Automatic' prefix on multiple properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface, where multiple properties need to have a prefix in their name, such this:

```js
interface b {
    'PREFIXfoo': number;
    'PREFIXbar': string;
    'PREFIXbaz': boolean;
}

let x: b = {
    PREFIXfoo: 1,
    PREFIXbar: '',
    PREFIXbaz: true,
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to get around specifying the PREFIX for every property, perhaps using a mapped type or similar.

Comment: Don't think you can do string manipulations in mapped types, but it would be a great feature :)

Comment: Relevant issue in GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754

Comment: It's implemented here:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336